# react - maximum update depth exceeded using react-table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Trying to include react-table in a basic app that takes input in a field, stores this in the components state when the field contents change, and then fetches data from Github on a button press.

Everything works fine until I add the line

`const tableInstance = useTable({columns, data})`

The page will load fine but the moment the input field changes (ie you type in it) the app crashes with the error:

**Error: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.**

The stack trace includes these snippets from the react-table library

hooks/useColumnVisibility.js

```
  204 | 
  205 | useMountedLayoutEffect(() => {
  206 |   if (getAutoResetHiddenColumns()) {
> 207 |     dispatch({ type: actions.resetHiddenColumns })
  208 | ^ }
  209 | }, [dispatch, columns])
  210 |
```

and publicUtils.js:

```
  153 | 
  154 | safeUseLayoutEffect(() => {
  155 |   if (mountedRef.current) {
> 156 |     fn()
  157 | ^ }
  158 |   mountedRef.current = true
  159 |   // eslint-disable-next-line
```

This is the code from my App.js file

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import {useTable} from "react-table"

function App() {

  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [keyword, setKeyword] = useState('');

  const fetchData = () => {
    const url = `https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=${keyword}`
    fetch(url)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(responseData => {
        setData(responseData.items);
      });
  }

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setKeyword(e.target.value);
  }

  const columns = [{
    Header: 'Name', //column header 
    accessor: 'full_name' //Value accessor
  }, {
    Header: 'URL',
    accessor: 'html_url'
  }, {
    Header: 'Owner',
    accessor: 'owner.login'
  }]

  const tableInstance = useTable({columns, data}) // line causing the problem

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input type="text" onChange={handleChange}/>
      <button onClick={fetchData} value={keyword} >Fetch</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Presumably, I've done something that causes the state to update every time the page is rendered thereby causing another render but I can't work out what it is. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 6):

Ok, so I fixed this by making a Table component that is then included in the App component DOM.

This is the updated code that fixes the issue

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import {useTable} from "react-table"

function Table({columns, data}){

  const {
    getTableProps,
    getTableBodyProps,
    headerGroups,
    rows,
    prepareRow,
  } = useTable({columns, data})

  return (
    <table {...getTableProps()}>
      <thead>
        {
          headerGroups.map(headerGroup => (
              <tr {...headerGroup.getHeaderGroupProps()}>
                {
                  headerGroup.headers.map( column => (
                    <th {...column.getHeaderProps()}>
                      {
                        column.render('Header')
                      }
                    </th>
                  ))
                }
              </tr>
          ))
        }
      </thead>
      <tbody {...getTableBodyProps()}>
        { // loop over the rows
          rows.map(row => {
            prepareRow(row)
            return (
              <tr {...row.getRowProps()}>
                { // loop over the rows cells 
                  row.cells.map(cell => (
                    <td {...cell.getCellProps()}>
                      {cell.render('Cell')}
                    </td>
                  ))
                }
              </tr> 
            )
          })
        }
        <tr>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  );
}

function App() {

  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [keyword, setKeyword] = useState('');

  const fetchData = () => {
    const url = `https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=${keyword}`
    fetch(url)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(responseData => {
        setData(responseData.items);
      });
  }

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setKeyword(e.target.value);
  }

  const columns = [{
    Header: 'Name', //column header 
    accessor: 'full_name' //Value accessor
  }, {
    Header: 'URL',
    accessor: 'html_url'
  }, {
    Header: 'Owner',
    accessor: 'owner.login'
  }]


  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input type="text" onChange={handleChange}/>
      <button onClick={fetchData} value={keyword} >Fetch</button>
      <Table 
        columns={columns} 
        data = {data}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

The trouble is I don't really know why this works or what the crux of the issue was in the first place.

Comment: This GitHub issue may shed some light on the issue: https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-table/issues/2369

Comment: None of these worked for me. Finally setting `autoResetHiddenColumns: false` solved the issue.

Comment: I had a similar issue
I have a react app with a router and when i tried to call a useState inside the routed component, I was getting an error about setting state multiple times or something like that, so instead of calling the `useTable` hook on my root component, I added it to the component that created the table

Comment: @ixaxaar You method works for me.